# What action should I take for answers without explanation?

Tags: discussion

Here one person posting code only answer to old questions without any explanation.

You can check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13822114/passing-parameters-to-controller-on-click-of-a-button/36418425#comment60452152_36418425) , [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/833997/validate-that-end-date-is-greater-than-start-date-with-jquery/36418130#comment60451824_36418130), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30873818/startdate-and-enddate-validation/36418092#comment60451817_36418092), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6135433/javascript-check-end-date-is-greater-than-or-equal-to-start-date/36418214#comment60451807_36418214), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14598098/java-script-for-end-date-greater-than-start-date/36418276#36418276) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11172938/end-date-greater-than-start-date-validation-javascript-not-working-properly/36418150#36418150).

It may be related to the question or may not. I have make comment that `add some explanation`.

But, it is enough to add comment? Or should I take some action on it like flag answer or anything else?

Comment: If you see a pattern, then use a custom mod flag. The mods will take care of this. If you see this only once, then raise a VLQ flag.

Comment: @TheLostMind Yeah 5 of the answer are same . In pattern

Comment: @TheLostMind Im curious, if I see code only or "try this $code" answers in the LQP queue, I usually "Looks OK" them, because bad as they are, they're still answers to the question...

Comment: @Magisch - That depends on the context. If a person just keeps on dumping code continually without proper explanation, then the mods should be notified.. If the code itself is self explanatory (some people might argue that there is no such thing as *self explanatory* code :P), then its not NAA, although you are free to flag it as VLQ.

Comment: @TheLostMind I have largely stopped using NAA and VLQ flags because I was getting _very_ inconsistent results in their handling.

Comment: All the answers except the first one are the same as well. Assuming they're all applicable answers for the questions, it looks like somebody may need to swing a dupehammer.

Comment: Looks like all except for one of those linked to from the question are deleted now..

Comment: I'm pretty sure we've been told multiple times in the past _not_ to use VLQ for things like this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This user posted all the answers you've linked us to during the last hour. I would have downvoted one of the answers and made a clear comment referring to all of his recent answers, something like:

> Many of your recent answers are suffering from bad quality, please consider adding explanation and not only code snippets.

If OP improved them, then cool. If not, you can consider flagging them.